# Rewrite SQL query to accept date difference condition in where clause

Tags: sql, join, group-by, hive

Below is the data in TestingTable1

```
BUYER_ID   |   ITEM_ID         |    CREATED_TIME
-----------+-------------------+------------------------
1345653        110909316904         2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653        151851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653        221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653        400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
1345653        310411560125         2012-07-09 16:09:49
1345653        120945302103         2012-07-09 13:40:23
1345653        261060982989         2012-07-09 09:02:21
```

Below is the data in TestingTable2

```
USER_ID   |   PRODUCT_ID           |    LAST_TIME
-----------+-------------------+-------------------
1345653       110909316904         2012-07-09 21:30:06
1345653       152851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653       221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653       400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
```

I need to Compare `TestingTable2` with `TestingTable1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`. And I need to find all (basically the count) the missing and mismatch entries in `TestingTable2` after comparing from `TestingTable1`. I created SQL fiddle for this-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d87b2/1

If you run my query in the SQL Fiddle, you will get output as-

```
BUYER_ID    ERROR
1345653       5
```

which is right as last `three` rows from `TestingTable1` is missing in `TestingTable2` and rest `two` are mismatch after comparison from `TestingTable1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`.

Now the complicated thing is starting.

**Problem Statement-**

In my current output, I am getting ERROR count as `5`. So if you see first row in both the tables `ITEM_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID` are same but `CREATED_TIME` and `LAST_TIME` is not same, and difference between those two times is of only `1 minute`. So currently I am reporting that as a mismatch, but what I need is that if the difference between them  is within `15 minutes range`, then I don't want to report as an error. So after implementing this feature in my current query, I will be getting error count as `4` because difference is within `15 minutes range` for the first row.

So after taking help from Stack Overflow, I found the solution for this, and below is the sql query that works fine in SQL server(which will give error count as 4) but not in Hive as `Hive supports only equality JOINS` and I cannot run the below query in Hive. So I need some other way of doing this problem. Is it possible to do the date difference condition in where clause somehow? `Basically how I can rewrite the below SQL query` in some other way such that it would fulfill my all the requirements above.

```
SELECT  TT.BUYER_ID,
        COUNT(*)
FROM    (
          SELECT    testingtable1.buyer_id,
                    testingtable1.item_id,
                    testingtable1.created_time
          FROM      testingtable2
                    RIGHT JOIN testingtable1
                        ON (
                             testingtable1.item_id = testingtable2.product_id
                             AND testingtable1.BUYER_ID = testingtable2.USER_ID
                             AND ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, testingtable1.created_time, testingtable2.last_time)) <= 15
                           )
          WHERE     testingtable2.product_id IS NULL
        ) TT
GROUP BY TT.BUYER_ID;
```

Expected Output that I need after implementing the above feature-

```
BUYER_ID    ERROR
1345653       4
```

**UPDATE:-**

AS Per Below WEST comment, the output only show ERROR count as 1, but it should be showing as 4. And also after removing the last row he added in his SQL fiddle, its not working and I am getting zero error, which is not right as there is already one error in the time difference.

Comment: @Dan, Can you help me out here on this question? I am not sure how should I move forward on this question as I am stuck on this for so long.

Comment: Does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99d23/12 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do an equijoin, and put your time comparison logic inside of a CASE expression with a SUM, instead of a COUNT?

```
SELECT  TT1.BUYER_ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(mi, TT1.created_time, TT2.last_time)) <= 15 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
            END) AS ERROR
FROM    testingtable1 TT1
        LEFT JOIN testingtable2 TT2
            ON (
                 TT1.item_id = TT2.product_id
                 AND TT1.BUYER_ID = TT2.USER_ID
               )
GROUP BY TT1.BUYER_ID;
```

You will need to convert the date arithmetic to whatever hive uses...

Here's a [MS Sql server SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99d23/11) which gets 4 errors returned.

Comment: I think you got confused, Currently I am getting error count as 5 because everything that is not matching I am reporting as an error. So after implementing this 15 minute window in the SQL query I should be getting error as 4. But your qyery gives only error as 1.

Comment: And also you have added one more row in TestingTable2 data. Try removing the row you added in your SQL fiddle, and then run your query. You will get error as `0` but there is one more error of date difference in that data, i.e first row as it has one minute difference.

Comment: And also I tried changing few data's and your query is not working for those.

Comment: That should be a simple fix, just a matter of doing an outer join instead of an inner join. Remember that I added the 15 minute window to indicate that a 1 minute difference isn't the same. I updated my answer.