# Count the Mismatch on date difference

Tags: sql, join, hive

Below is the data in Table1

```
BUYER_ID   |   ITEM_ID         |    CREATED_TIME
-----------+-------------------+------------------------
1345653        110909316904         2012-07-09 21:29:06
1345653        151851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653        221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653        400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
1345653        310411560125         2012-07-09 16:09:49
1345653        120945302103         2012-07-09 13:40:23
1345653        261060982989         2012-07-09 09:02:21
```

Below is the data in Table2

```
USER_ID   |   PRODUCT_ID           |    LAST_TIME
-----------+-------------------+----------------------
1345653       110909316904         2012-07-09 21:30:06
1345653       151851771618         2012-07-09 19:57:33
1345653       221065796761         2012-07-09 19:31:48
1345653       400307563710         2012-07-09 18:57:33
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I need to Compare `Table2` with `Table1` on `BUYER_ID` and `USER_ID`. And I need to find the count of mismatch if difference between `CREATED_TIME` and `LAST_TIME` is greater than `15 minutes`

So if you look at the above example, see the first row in both the tables `ITEM_ID` and `PRODUCT_ID` are same but `CREATED_TIME` and `LAST_TIME` is not same, and difference between those two times is of only 1 minute. So if difference is greater than 15 minutes then I want to show them as an error. So expected output will be for above case-

```
BUYER_ID    ERROR
1345653       1
```

Comment: Just for completeness, which database are you using?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?  Postgres?  Something else?

Comment: I am working in Hive and Hive supports SQL like syntax, but to add one more point here that I think will be useful as Hive supports only `EQUALITY JOINS` and `<=15` will not work in JOIN conditions but in where clause we can add this `<=15`. I know how to deal with date functions in Hive, I am just looking for solution so that I can modify it to work in Hive environment. I think SQL Server syntax will works fine here.

Comment: [You posted this question already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619008/rewrite-sql-query-to-accept-date-difference-condition-in-where-clause/). Please don't repost.

Comment: Yes I posted that but in that I am overall trying to find the count for everything, but in this case question is same but I need output different, Those two are same question but the requirement is different.

Comment: @rjchar It's virtually identical. You can use the same query that I put there, just use a regular JOIN instead of a outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find all the buyers that have a match:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.buyer_id = t2.user_id and
        datediff(min, t1.created_time, t2.last_time) between -15 and 15
```

Using this, now find the cases where there is no match:

```
with matches as (
     select *
     from table1 t1 join
          table2 t2
          on t1.buyer_id = t2.user_id and
             datediff(min, t1.created_time, t2.last_time) between -15 and 15
    )
select *
from table1 t1 left outer join
     matches m
     on t1.buyer_id = m.user_id and
        t1.product_id = m.product_id and
        t1.created_time = m.created_time
where m.buyer_id is null
```

Comment: Can you provide me some sql fiddle example where I can see whether it is working or not?